# Are balanced lines possible in LaTeX?

Tags: book-design, grid-typesetting

This question comes a little too late for me, but as it is an interesting question, I will ask it anyway.

When I was designing my book, I was wondering whether I should use spaced or indented paragraphs. I also asked this question at [GraphicDesign.SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/161494/spaced-paragraphs-vs-indented-paragraphs-in-academic-textbooks/) and got different answers.

However, when an answer was in favour of indented paragraphs, such as [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/161494/spaced-paragraphs-vs-indented-paragraphs-in-academic-textbooks/164598#164598), the main or even the only argument was that **the lines in a professionally designed book should be balanced**, i.e. the lines should run across the spread (please click on the link to see an example).

I have been working with LaTeX for decades and have never seen or heard of a document created with LaTeX in which the lines are balanced, e.g. that the text after a formula or figure starts on the baseline of the pre-defined grid. I apologise for my ignorance: is such a thing common or even possible in LaTeX?

Comment: The problem with asking graphic designers about graphic design, is similar to the problem with asking automobile owners about automobiles. What I do: Go to a library that has well-received books (paper or digital) of the kind you are trying to write, addressed to the audience that you intend to reach. Then, do that!

Comment: @rallg Thank you for the response.  But this is not the issue here and my book is already out.  I just want to establish whether this idea of balanced lines is at all plausible in LaTeX.

Comment: If you have only text and the page layout is setup correctly you get grid typesetting. As soon as you have elements like math or floats or sectioning it is not natural. It is not impossible but requires careful checking of the spaces and in various places you must insert commands "to return" to the grid.

Comment: This is often called "grid typesetting" (I think!). See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668366/context-grid-layout-but-not-for-headings-figures-tables-etc ; there is even a tag but it's a bit --- ehem -- abused: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-typesetting

Comment: it is possible but tex doesn't help much, its model of stretch glue space doesn't match well with grid typesetting but it is certainly possible.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So would it be fair to say that neither technically oriented books (with a lot of floats) nor LaTeX are quite appropriate for grid typesetting?

Comment: yes, but you should also consider if grid typesetting is actually needed. If you have only text you see the shift in the lines, but if there are lots of various font sizes and math and pictures etc then most things don't align anyway.

Comment: If "balanced" means "grid typesetting," it is certainly possible with LaTeX. Not hard with ordinary running text. Images, floats, diagrams, tables, etc., are another story. Also another story if you change text size. Nevertheless, still possible, if you are willing to apply manual padding where needed, so that "funky object"+"padding" together occupy an integral number of baselines. Much more difficult if "funky object" splits columns or pages. Also remember that readers are increasingly adapted to non-PDF Ebooks, with non-grid layout (and various aspect ratios).

Comment: See the grid package https://ctan.org/pkg/grid?lang=en It is an interesting package and write-up by RiverValley who work as Consultants and publishers using LaTeX. If you willing to typeset your book page by page (like Graphic Designers do) it is possible.  With books having math is almost impossible once you have inline math.  With lots of small figures, many math books push the figures in the margin. I.e many of Stewart books do that.

Comment: The question is not if you should use  a grid typesetting, but when: (1): Thin paper  that almost shows through, so  overlap text of both sides is a must, and/or  (2) You want to impress readers  who probably don't give a damn about the grid layout,  or cannot notice the difference.

Comment: @Fran As I said, the issue here is not whether one should use it, but whether it is possible to do so in LaTeX. Whether one should use it was discussed in the question I referenced in my OP. If you look at the question, you will see that some professional designers feel pretty strongly that grid spacing is the only correct/professional way to do. You can argue with them about it there :)

Comment: @Pygmalion I know the arguments of authority at this respect but the goals and taste of professional designers and each LaTeX user are not necessarily the same. My comment was not about if that  is possible because has been already answered by others (in brief: a bit, but it is a pain).

Comment: @Fran Well, if a LaTeX user (me) wants to publish a **real** book and do the typesetting themself (so that the equations and figures look nice and blend perfectly into the text), then it is in that user's interest to make the typesetting as professional as possible. The best of both worlds would be a professional designer who is familiar with and uses LaTeX, but this is extremely rare.  When a LaTeX user works on a book for years, they want it to look as perfect as possible.

Comment: @Pygmalion  For sure, if your personal costs/benefits ratio is low, go ahead, no doubt.  Just do not  forget the costs.  Obtain a grid layout in LaTeX  it is not trivial and have  drawbacks. The grid approach have a limited flexibility, and it also matter the suitability of your particular contents to fit to this approach. Relying too much on a grid system could hinder your creativity,  or produce a rigid and monotonous structures.

Answer (score 4):

Grid typesetting is possible in LaTeX, provided you are willing to work like a Graphic Designer, page by page. Having said that one day when the Output Routine is hacked extensively to work 2-pages at a time it maybe possible to automate some cases.See the grid package [grid](https://ctan.org/pkg/grid?lang=en) for an example of what is possible today.

[image: grid package]

To see some of the problems and the contradictions present , refer to the image. Notice the text in the first paragraph, that balances. Now what would happen if in one of these paragraphs, you have inline math? Some of the lines will then be misaligned. In this particular example The heading on the right page was used to fill the page.

Note that Graphic Designers, in the early days of the web, used to code HTML pages in tables, so that it produced grid-layouts! This approach can work with LaTeX today also.

Easy thing today to go half-way, in a book with a lot of images standardize on the height of the images, so if you get two images on top of each page they will balance nicely. But then you might end up like Bernard Shaw, who is reputed that on occasions he changed whole galleys of text to get a hyphen where he wanted; thankfully we don't have this problem using LaTeX.

Comment: Bernard Shaw is not alone. I have rewritten the occasional book chapter (20 pages running text, nothing but text) to eliminate all hyphens. Just as a writing exercise. My `novel` package is pre-configured for grid layout. It achieves this by removing support for math, diagrams, and tables (!), setting the plus/minus glues to zero, and padding raster images to certain sizes.

Comment: Amazing!   Just curious, your book is only text?

Comment: All my books are only text. I do no math. That's why my own document class is `novel` rather than `feynman` or `planck`. Also, since the writing is monolingual and original (I can edit everything), that allows a lot of flexibility. One advantage of the English language is that is vocabulary has many words derived from different linguistic sources, and there are few conjugations, so it is usually possible to write something with a few more (or fewer) letters.

Comment: @rallg I had a quick glance at the code at gihub has an impressive amount of detail. Perhaps you should also provide an answer, with some details as to how you have achieved the grid layout, motivation etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem to set a few TeX primitive registers to fixed size (they are not fixed by default, for example `\parskip`, `\abovedisplayskip`, ...) and to create a macros for section titles etc. so that they respect the grid. And to create more macros for images or inserted tables which measure the height of this material, calculates the space above and below it in order that the new height is in integer multiple of `\baselineskip`.

I explain why this grid setting isn't default in typical TeX macro collections. One of the basic typesetting rule is that the first and last line of each page is at the same position (exception is chapter titles and chapter last pages). This rule cannot be simply met without stretchable vertical glues, because we have another typesetting rule: forbidden widows and orphans in the paragraphs, forbidden orphan section titles.

I recommend following procedure in my book [TeXbook inside out](https://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/tbn/tbn.pdf) for grid typesetting:

- set all related TeX primitive registers to fixed value (i.e. no stretch no shrink components),
- set `\vsize` to integer multiply of `\baselineskip` plus one `\topskip`,
- create macros for section titles and image insertions as mentioned above (these macros are in the "TeXbook inside out" presented),
- set `\widowpenalty=10000`, `\clubpenalty=10000`,
- and do following:

Try to TeX the document and see the log file for the first occurrence "Underfull vbox while output is active". Open the pdf and think about how to solve the inconsistency of the line numbers at the given page (reported in log as underfull). Typically, you can try to apply nonzero `\looseness` for some paragraph which precedes the problem. This may change the number of lines in this selected paragraph. Try to TeX the document again and look at the next "Underfull vbox while output is active", etc.

You can see that this needs intensive human intervention when typesetting the document. Maybe, today the machines are able to do more than the time when TeX is born and the process should be more automated. But the optimization task which takes the text of the whole chapter and finds the optimum of function of typesetting aesthetic has exponential complexity. There is also a big problem to formulate a good function which measures this typesetting aesthetic.

Answer (score 2):

Grid layout (balanced lines) is possible in LaTeX. I use LuaLaTeX, which adds the capability
to do some additional tricks, but they are not necessary at the basic level.

To see how this works, look in the <texmf-dist/tex/latex/base> directory.
Open the various `*.clo` files in a text editor, and see what they do.
Much of the code involves setting various "glues" and "skips" and "penalties"
to values that are deemed appropriate.

But those values make some assumptions about what it is that you are writing.
The primary purpose of TeX was, and still is, mathematical typesetting.
Running text (paragraphs) take second place.

A characteristic of mathematical expressions, as well as diagrams and other
objects that are not running text, is that they do not need to conform to
grid layout. In fact, many math formulas look much worse, if you force them
to the text grid. So, standard LaTeX assumes that you have a lot of white space,
and that you also have objects (formulas, diagrams, tables) for which you do not
know the height and width at the time you create them. Compare that to raster
images, which have known pixel sizes, from which you can calculate the print size
before you insert them into a LaTeX document.

If you create a document that uses only running text, then it is not hard to
place the text on grid. This involves setting several *.clo variables to
zero (or one, or some other fixed value). That makes for "rigid" page layout
rather than the flexible layout provided by flexible glues.

You will need to use a fixed point size in running text: No `\large` or anything
like that. You will need to use a fixed baseline skip. Be aware that some
packages change the baseline skip when their macros are used, so you will
need to avoid loading some packages. Ah, but what about chapter titles, section titles, and all those other LaTeX automations? They use larger text, and insert whitespace. Too bad, so sad. You will need to adjust their sizes, or (easier) pad them, after you see preliminary results. In my own non-technical work, I never use those automations. Maybe I cannot do much math, but I can count chapters.

You will need to avoid crowding the number of lines per page. Reason: If lines
are too tight, then they will automatically be spread apart (off-grid) when you
type an unusually tall or deep character. Word processors also do this.

You will need to pad the size of objects (images, diagrams, tables, etc.)
so that they displace an integral number of text lines. This is tricky in the
case of floating objects. The best strategy is to pre-compose those objects,
one at a time. Then you can see how much space they must occupy, and
calculate how much padding you will need to add (perhaps with `\vspace*`).

If your book is printed to paper (not Ebooks or any kind), then this is
easier: You do not need the resize capability of vector graphics, because
you cannot resize paper. If you convert all vector objects to raster,
then place them as `*.png` or `*.jpg` images, it will be easier to calculate
padding.

Note that many paper-book publishers will reject page layout with an object
continued across the spine binding. This has to do with manufacturing,
not TeX or PDF.

You will need to be careful with certain LaTeX environments, such as `minipage`.
In many cases, text alignment is relative to a prior character depth, instead
of text baseline. Solutions for that problem can be found on this site.

I did not provide a list of what you need to set, and their values, because
it may depend on what you are doing.

If your book involves a lot of objects other than running text, you may find it
easier to use a modern word processor, or page layout program. Those are pre-set
for grid layout, and will automatically pad objects. Generally, they will not
typeset running text as nicely as does LaTeX. But they are better than they were
20 years ago, and thanks to Ebooks, readers are used to mediocre typesetting.

Final note: Whatever you do, be sure to choose a main font that looks good for
your intended purpose. If it is paper-print, the default Latin Modern Roman may be too light. I suggest Libertinus Serif.